# C++: no matching function call

Tags: c++, tree

I am getting the above error and its pointing to my call for add(root, node). What does this error mean? I have tried moving the private add to the top but that doesnt work either. Also, it cant be because its private because its in the same class, right?

```
class Tree{

    public:
        Node *root;
        Tree(Node *r){
            root = r;
        }

        void add(Node node){
            add(root, node);//error here
        }
    private:
        void add(Node parent, Node node){

            if(parent == root && root == nullptr){
                root = node;
            }

            if(parent == nullptr){
                parent(node->value, nullptr, nullptr);
            }
            else if(node > parent){
                add(parent->right, node);
            }
            else {
                add(parent->left, node);
            }
```

Comment: nullptr checks for a pointer, your parameters are no pointers! Is that a typo/copy-paste-error or (part of) the problem?

Comment: else if(node > parent) strange..

Comment: @JerryGoyal Looks like they're trying to heap sort, and they should have `else if(node->value > parent->value)`, they're code has a number of other issues too

Comment: I think it's code for binary search tree

Comment: I turned my two parameters pointers but that still does not fix the error. I also fixed my careless mistake when comparing node > parent.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs the signature

```
void add(Node* parent, Node* node)
```

Note that these are `Node*` instead of `Node`. The same goes for the `public` overload of that function

```
void add(Node* node)
```

This is apparent because 1) you are doing comparisons to `nullptr` and 2) you keep dereferencing your variables with `->` instead of `.`

Answer (score 0):

CoryKramer has spotted some errors, I'll add this also.

you can't compare pointers so it should be data:

```
else if(node->value > parent->value){
            add(parent->right, node);
```